# mongodb client side sharding

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, sharding

The mongodb [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#production-configuration) is very powerful but with a complicated and resource occupied deployment.

Sometimes we only need to partition by Month to archive the in-active data. Is there any practice for this.
for example we can create collection like
order_201801
order_201802
etc..

But if we using this dynamic collection name, we can't use the power of [spring-data-mongo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to do? It sounds like you may be interested in partitioning data by time period rather than distributing across multiple servers based on sharding. To keep data for the current month (or an arbitrary time period), one approach would be to write data into a new collection per time period (eg. `data-201804`). You could then archive older collections (for example, `mongodump` & drop) once they are no longer active. However, this will complicate queries that span several time periods as you'd need to join data from multiple collections.

Comment: Thanks stennie, see my edit. Yes, we will write data into the collection by month. But if we adopt this, we can't use the power of spring-data-mongo, like the [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

Comment: To be even clearer with your question, I'd edit the last line to ask how best to use dynamic collection names with Spring Data rather than suggesting this isn't possible. It would also be relevant to mention your specific version of Spring Data. Another option to consider would be using the [POJO support](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/bson/pojos/) in the underlying MongoDB Java driver (3.5+), but that's probably a separate question if your intent is to remain within Spring Data abstractions.